# add columns and rows in a dataGridView which is in different form

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

I am a beginner in c#, I have two forms `mainForm` and `subForm`. The `mainForm` has `DataGridView1` and the `subForm` has `richTextBox1`.

I want to add rows and columns to `DataGridView1` from `subForm` through *FormClosingEvent*

I made the `DataGridView1` modifier to *public* . It is showing in intellisense of `subForm` but maybe I am doing something wrong.

I have tried the below code in my `subForm` *FormClosingEvent* but I cant see any update to my `DataGridView1`.

```
   if (richTextBox1.Text != "")
        {
            mainForm newMainForm = new mainForm();
            newMainForm.dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
            newMainForm.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Product ID";
            newMainForm.dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Product Name";
            newMainForm.dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Product Price";

            string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000" };
            newMainForm.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "2", "Product 2", "2000" };
            newMainForm.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "3", "Product 3", "3000" };
            newMainForm.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "4", "Product 4", "4000" };
            newMainForm.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);               
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: At a glance, you are not setting the DataGridView1 property on the correct _instance_ of the mainForm (you declare a new instance in the subForm, when I expect the mainForm is already open?).  If the mainForm is responsible for opening the subform, try passing an instance of `this` from the mainForm to the subForm.  The subForm can store that in a variable, and use it to manipulate the mainForm. - Note, far from being ideal but is probably the easiest way.

Comment: `mainForm newMainForm = new mainForm();` will create a new instance and this is not the one which is open and you will not find these changes shown, you will have to get the mainform instance which is open

Comment: ohh k then how to add the changes to that mainForm only, not its instance?  I cant even use mainForm directly..

Comment: @Smudge202 yes you are right. the mainForm is open. I cant understand the explanation you have given about `this`. How to pass the instance from mainForm to subForm. Pls dont be annoyed I am new to c# :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So assuming your mainForm opens your subForm:

```
subForm sub = new SubForm();
sub.Show(); // or however you have done it
```

In your example, you need the subForm to be able to change something on the mainform, so, create a Public/Internal method on the subForm, similar to this:

```
private mainForm _parent;

internal void RegisterParent(mainForm form)
{
    // error handling of course, make sure form is not null, or you don't already have a parent
    this._parent = form;
}
```

In the mainform, after `subForm.Show()`, add something like:

```
sub.RegisterParent(this);
```

Now your subForm can manipulate the correct mainform *instance*:

```
if (richTextBox1.Text != "")
    {
        _parent.dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
        _parent.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Product ID";
        _parent.dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Product Name";
        _parent.dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Product Price";

        string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000" };
        _parent.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "2", "Product 2", "2000" };
        _parent.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "3", "Product 3", "3000" };
        _parent.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "4", "Product 4", "4000" };
        _parent.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);               
    }
```

I hope that helps!